# Putting method calls into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, progress-bar, process

I was adding a loading bar feature to my program in Java and I was wondering if I could set a list of processes that need to be done, so that it knows how many processes it needs to complete.

For example, saving them as strings?

```
ArrayList<String> processes = new ArrayList<String>();
processes.add("CSVWriter.createFileOfCompany(\"Random Company\");");
processes.add("FileConverter.convertCSVToXLS(classPath + 
    \"/Output/Random_Company.csv\");");

for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) {
    // run process
    // update loading bar
}
```

These aren't real methods to my program, but they are pretty similar to what I want to accomplish.

I'm sure this isn't the best way, but I want to have some way to create a list like this so I know how many processes there are before I run them. I have a system set up to break down these processes even further and show their progress, so this bar is pretty precise at the moment, but I have to number each of the processes =/.

Maybe I'm just missing the point. Creating progress bars is totally new to me.

If there are any good articles on progress bar creation, feel free to send them my way as well. Keep in mind that I'm not using an actual swing-based GUI. This bar is all S.O.P text.

Many thanks,

Justian Meyer

Comment: Are you assuming that all your methods are going to take an equal amount of time to run?

Comment: I don't expect them to. I basically want to break down the methods into equal blocks. If there are 5 calls, it will be divided into 5 blocks. Each of these blocks will receive information from the loops in the methods to slowly fill them. Imagine it like this `[///// | ///// | ///// | ///// | /////]`................................... `[///// | ///// | //... | ..... | .....]` means that the first two processes are done and 2/5 of process 3 is done. Of course, it would look more like: `[////////////.............] 48%`

Comment: My method for creating this is not really as clean as I'd like, so I'm totally open to better ideas.

Comment: I answered your question literally below, but this is really not the best way to implement a progress bar for script execution.  The traditional way is to manually report your progress after every statement.  Remember that not all commands take the same amount of time.

Comment: @Gunslinger47: What do you mean by manually report? Like: "Creating file [filename]... done", "Converting file [filename]... done"? That just doesn't look as clean =/. Trying to make my cheap GUI look as friendly as possible. It's basically a click-and-go program.

Comment: Something like `progressBar.reportProgress(48)` when you're 48% done.

Comment: @Gunslinger47: Hmm... I'm not such a big fan of that approach. Once I introduce settings, there's no telling what the process flow may look like. That's why I wanted to create an ArrayList. That can't really be how they'd do it, right? That just seems so... :/

Comment: [That's how it's done.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29)  There are accuracy and maintanance issues of course.  You might consider asking a new question specifically regarding the best way to handle a progress bar in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Closures will hopefully be coming soon in the next version of Java, but until then you can use anonymous classes implementing a known interface:

```
List<Runnable> jobs = new ArrayList<Runnable>();

jobs.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        CSVWriter.createFileOfCompany("Random Company");
    }
});

jobs.add(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        FileConverter.convertCSVToXLS(classPath + "/Output/Random_Company.csv");
    }
});

for (Runnable job : jobs) {
    job.run();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Runnable or Callable (if you need to be able to throw exception) instead of creating own 'Job' interface.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @Sanity.  I was in the middle of it myself.  I decided to go with a custom interface originally to better illustrate the idea, however that was just adding noise.

Comment: Yes, maybe for explaining the idea, custom interface was better :-)

Comment: Oh! I remember seeing this concept floating around in one of my old textbooks. Such a cool idea :). Thanks so much for the help. +1 for clean post and +1 for sanity for great edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a scheme that just came to my mind:

```
interface WorkProcess
    void setWorkUnits(int units)
    void setArguments(Object obj1,...)
    void execute()
```

So you encapsulate all your tasks with an interface that does `execute` as per the classic command pattern; it's also told (see below) how much work that job will probably take. You'll probably want some mechanism to pass data into these tasks for them to work with.

```
class WorkProcessFactory
    static WorkProcess makeWorkProcess()
    static int getTotalWorkUnitsAllocated()
    static synchronized int reportWorkDone(int units)
    static void addProgressListener(ProgressListener xxx)
```

When you have a job to do, you ask the factory to churn out one of these processes for you. In doing so, it does the estimate on work units and passes that to the WorkProcess it just created. It also keeps a tally of the total of those units for setting up the top of the progress indicator. One cool side effect of this is that you don't have to wait for all your jobs to be prepared: You can increment the maximum value for your progress report every time you add a job even as jobs are being processed and newly created; your bar will always show a realistic ratio.

You can stuff your WorkProcesses into a queue of some sort. `ExecutorService` comes to mind if your WorkProcess also implements the `Runnable` interface (which is a good idea). You'll be at liberty to process those jobs sequentially single-file or concurrently - whatever your execution queue machinery supports.

The WorkProcess' `execute()` method basically wraps the `run()` method (or maybe the other way around, since ExecutorService expects a run() method but our work unit magic is in `execute()`); but when that's done, it conscientiously calls back to `reportWorkDone` with the number of units it was told its job was worth. Upon receiving these reports, the factory has an updated value for units of work done, which it can report back to the snooping ProgressListener. That, in turn, updates the bar in the GUI.

Done. (I think). Probably needs some refining.